# Boolean Logic - Can B'(AD)' + A'C'D + AC be simplified any further?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I think I hit a point where I am stuck.

Can `B'(AD)' + A'C'D + AC` any further?

Let's say it is simplified enough - I want to get rid of the addition via deMorgan's law. Is it okay to have the same variables twice? Using `A'B' = (A+B)'` law and `(AB)' = A' + B'` law.

I feel like it would get messy, but I want to get rid of the addition (OR operator)

Comment: It can be simplified, since you still have brackets inside an implicant.
This is not yet in Disjunctive normal form.

I don't understand why you want to get rid of the "+" though.

Also you could try to use a Karnaugh Map for simplification.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to simplify program logic, then maybe a binary decision diagram (BDD) for this function can help you. Here it is (using the optimal variable ordering):

[image]